# android getExternalStoragePublicDirectory unable to write in 4.4.2 paticularly in Smasung S3

Tags: android, android-storage

The directory was not able to write in android 4.4.2

```
 File pdfDir=newFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory  
 (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"PdfFolder");
```

Also, i used manifest **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "PdfFolder")
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has requested the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, then it is always permitted to write to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) even in KitKat, as getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() points to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) ("SDCard") on the vast majority of devices.